# How can I change TermFreVector in Lucene 4.0

Tags: lucene

Here is the code:

```java
public int docLength(String filename) throws IOException {
    int length = 0;
    TermFreqVector t = indexReader.getTermFreqVector(0, "contents");
    for (int i = 0; i < t.getTermFrequencies().length; i++) {
        length += t.getTermFrequencies()[i];
    }
    return length;
}

public int docLength(int id) throws IOException {
    int length = 0;
    TermFreqVector t = indexReader.getTermFreqVector(id, "contents");
    for (int i = 0; i < t.getTermFrequencies().length; i++) {
        length += t.getTermFrequencies()[i];
    }
    return length;
}
```

The error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    TermFreqVector cannot be resolved to a type
    The method getTermFreqVector(int, String) is undefined for the type IndexReader

    at BM25.docLength(BM25.java:96)
    at BM25.avgDocLength(BM25.java:130)
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing and traversing term vectors changed significantly in 4.0.  The [Migration Guide](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html) is a very helpful resource on that and other changes from 3.6 to 4.0.

In this case, you'll need to access a `Terms` instance through a call to `IndexReader.getTermVector`:

```java
int length = 0;
TermEnum terms = indexReader.getTermVector(id, "contents").iterator();
while (terms.next())
    length += terms.totalTermFreq(null);
return length;
```